# Does Document Count change for a Index while using Dynamic Template over Static Template?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Data is coming from the Same Source but when I go do **discover** I see the same Number of Hits for both the Indexes.

Command : `Get _Cat/indices`

Dynamic Template Count:
DynamicTempIndex,            ZvjfHIkPTR6lb5as7CsZrQ,   30 ,   1 ,    6692850,     0,    3.6gb,  1.8gb

Static Template Count:
StaticTempIndex,            EgdEtNuaQQeSUA_8wX9y6g, 30,  1,   6612017,       0,     3gb,   1.5gb

Comment: check your elasticsearch log after static template index complete, might be possible it is not indexing some document due to mapping exception.

Comment: Checked logs Could not find anything related to any documents facing exception.